# stop qtp from initially restarting when ran from ALM remotely

Tags: remote-access, qtp, alm

I have a question about my qtp 11.0 restarting when I launch a test script from ALM. is there a way to run the from the already open qtp from ALM using a remote connection? the remote agent is already set so that QTP does not close when running a test set.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. in addition to selecting the remote agent you must only select web when launching qtp the first time.

Comment: If the set of addins associated with the test isn't compatible with the addins selected in the active QTP then ALM will close QTP and open it with the correct addins.